# css3 repeating-linear-gradient - get fine-grained pattern?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I would like to create a fine-grained background pattern that alternates between diagonal red  and blue lines, each just a couple of pixels in width.

I'm not sure I'm understanding the rules of repeating linear gradients

For example you would think what I want is something like this:

```
p {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, red 3px, blue 3px)
}
```

but that renders entirely blue.

[Here is an example](http://jsbin.com/uyixok/1/)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '3px' you put there is an offset from the start, not a relative offset from the last color stop.

If you want to see alternating colors (without a gradient), you would need something different:

```
body {
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, red 0px, red 3px, blue 3px, blue 6px);
}
```

The gradient starts with red (`red 0px`). Then goes to red the next three pixels (`red 3px`). Then changes to blue (`blue 3px`) and makes the next three pixels blue (`blue 6px`).

See http://jsfiddle.net/uhB3G/1/ (works only in current Firefox, IIRC FF 17+)

Comment: as you noted, firefox (and safari) display the stripes just fine, but chrome shows a very irregular pattern. do you know a good fallback solution?

Comment: ok so I found a workaround for the irregular rendering in chrome by setting the background-size property to an appropriate value.

Comment: I think it's a bug in Chrome.